# Find the value of a single attribute or element

Tags: go

Lets say i have an xml:

```
<test>
    <something id="" />
</test>
```

How do i get the value of id without the hassle of creating a struct? Is that possible? If not, is there a short hand to find the value of id?

Comment: Just curious.. why don't you want to define a struct? Being a "hassle" doesn't seem like a good enough reason. Of course there are work arounds, but my suggestion would be to use a struct here, or to use a regexp + FindStringSubmatch.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 well, lets say i have a huge xml file, and i only want this one specific value that could be buried deep in a bunch of elements. Creating a struct is a pure annoyance. I just need a quick search to get to find the one matching attribute with minimal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions of scanner are not the perfect solution, because in complicated xml can happen, that you it won't find good id. It also does not solve problem with chars like &amp; .. Only solution is Unmarshal, although, you don't have to describe a structure of elements, that don't bother you.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Something struct {
        Id string `xml:"id,attr"`
    }
    type Result struct {
        //XMLName xml.Name `xml:"test"`
        Something    Something   `xml:"something"`
    }
    var v Result

    data := `
<test>
   <something id="123"/>
   <tag_that_i_ignore id="aaa" attr="???"/>
</test>
    `
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Result: %#v\n\n", v)
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/x5eFvdhpTW

Comment: Thank you sir. I was hoping there would be an even simpler form with a struct, like type Result struct { Id string `xml:"something>id"` } But i suppose this will do

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's less hassle but you could dig the value out "manually" doing something like:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
for scanner.Scan() {
   scannedText := scanner.Text()
   i := strings.Index(scannedText, `id="`) + len(`id="`)
   j := strings.Index(scannedText[i:], `"`) + i
   id, _ := strconv.Atoi(scannedText[i:j])
}
```

I didn't test this snipped but have used this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

While using struct is the proper way, you can use regexp to match it:

```
var idRe = regexp.MustCompile(`<something[^>]+?id="([^"]+)"[^>]+`)

func FindIDs(in string) []string {
    vals := idRe.FindAllStringSubmatch(in, -1)
    out := make([]string, len(vals))
    for i, v := range vals {
        out[i] = v[1]
    }
    return out
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/iK7M6eXlzY)